# Flutter Http post call Doesn't work on web and works on mobile only

Tags: flutter, http, dart, web

```
  loginUser(email, password) async {
    var url = Uri.parse
        .call("https://us-central1-agenie-webapp.cloudfunctions.net/api/login");
    final http.Response response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{'email': email, 'password': password}),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) return response.body;
    return null;
  }
```

This is the api post call when I run this on web localhost with flutter run ,when I click on login button that calls this function on pressed it open a window in vscode named browser_client.dart and goes to line 69 where it shows :

```
 unawaited(xhr.onError.first.then((_) {
      // Unfortunately, the underlying XMLHttpRequest API doesn't expose any
      // specific information about the error itself.
      completer.completeError(
          ClientException('XMLHttpRequest error.', request.url),
          StackTrace.current);
    }));
```

Any solutions ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you trying to use the dio package (https://pub.dev/packages/dio), it worked in my web project.

Comment: Can you please provide code sample for post method using dio?

Comment: Here is an example from the package pub page: `response = await dio.post(
  'http://www.dtworkroom.com/doris/1/2.0.0/test',
  data: {'aa': 'bb' * 22}
);` You can find more here: https://pub.dev/packages/dio#examples